# ON COLUMNS compared to ON ROWS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

Why in `MDX` is it ok to do the following:

```
SELECT
[MyDim].[MyHier].[MyLevel] ON COLUMNS
FROM [CubeName]
```

But *not* the following:

```
SELECT
[MyDim].[MyHier].[MyLevel] ON ROWS
FROM [CubeName]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never find any good reason for that ;-) on columns, on rows are defining the 'shape' of the result (the tuples being exactly the same) and it has been decided that on columns only is ok but not on rows only; i.e.:

```
a | b | c
1 | 2 | 3
```

but not:

```
a | 1 
b | 2
c | 3
```

weird as I see no problem to return those values from an MDX server implementation point of view. By the way, no columns and no rows is valid :

```
select from [cube]
```

Comment: I agree - the choice of what is valid and what is not seems arbitrary

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a hierarchy of axises. `Columns` is the first and minimal part in  defining a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487118.aspx):

> When you specify an axis for a set (in this case composed of a single tuple) in a query, you must begin by specifying a set for the column axis before specifying a set for the row axis. The column axis can also be referred to as axis(0) or simply 0.

So you should first define `Columns`, then `Rows`, then `Pages` and so on.

```
<SELECT query axis clause> ::=
   [ NON EMPTY ] Set_Expression
   [ <SELECT dimension property list clause> ] 
      ON 
            Integer_Expression 
       | AXIS(Integer) 
       | COLUMNS 
       | ROWS 
       | PAGES 
       | SECTIONS 
       | CHAPTERS
```

Comment: +1 thanks Stoleg - I'm trying to hit the basics to get some understanding of this mysterious language

Comment: Just imagine you have a 3D cube and you need to get a value from inside this cube by defining coordinated of the value. This helps me a lot.

Comment: ok Stoleg thanks - so a tuple is a point on two of the sides of this imaginary cube and the value is where they intersect inside the cube? - but if I look at the following the how can this imaginary cube help ... [QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234716/extracting-second-value-from-ordered-list)

Comment: Tuple is a point (which we see as a numeric value) inside the cube, and members are "coordinates" of this point.